# Como ler um retorno Map<String, String> Java no javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Ao fazer uma requisição a um controle java que retorna um mapa de chave e valor "String":

```
@ControllerSupport
public Map< String, String > teste() {
    Map< String, String > teste = new HashMap< String, String >();
    teste.put( "Teste", "Teste" );
    return teste;
}
```

Ao imprimir a requisição atribuída a variável que acessa o serviço.

```
console.log($scope.teste);
```

Retornou ujm erro no log do javascript.

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

Como fazer para pegar este valor retornado do Map no Javascrip?

Comment: Esta variável recebe o valor do serviço que então busca o valor no controller do java no back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para determinar com certeza o problema teria que ter o código que faz a chamada, mas baseado em [duas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to) [respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409220/error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to-contain-an-object-but-got) do SO com a mesma mensagem de erro, posso supor que o problema pode ser corrigido usando uma das soluções abaixo.

1. Você pode adicionar `isArray: false` se estiver usando a ação `query`, assim:

   'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
2. Ou pode tentar usar a ação `get` ao invés de `query`.

Comment: Realmente estava setando que a requisição seria um vetor, com esta modificação para false agora esta pegando o objeto certinho. Obrigado!!